# Website visits count without using database

Tags: html, css

I am working on html website which uses no database just information to be displayed. Can i count the number of visits the website gets without using database. And how will i get the count whether through some code or through my hosting admin?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at Google analytics?

Comment: Hello. Can we have more information about your webserver please ? IIS, Apache, Nginx, ...

Answer (score 0):

There are free sites on the internet that give you the code to put an invisible tracking counter on your website .
You make an account with them and log in to check all your website stats

Comment: Thanks will check for it

Answer (score -1):

[**Google Analytics**](https://www.google.com/intl/nl_be/analytics/) would be the way to go. It's free and very powerful!

If you need to show some of your traffic data somewhere on your website, you might want to consider using the [**Analytics Core Reporting API**](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/) to fetch the data from your Analytics account.